# Getting the most nested list in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am migrating some LISP functions to Clojure. I have problems with StackOverflow message for the following functions:

```
(defn m
    [list depth]
    (cond 
        (= list nil) depth
        (atom (first list)) (m (rest list) depth)
        (> (m (first list) (+ depth 1)) (m (rest list) depth))  (m (first list) (+ depth 1))
        :default (m (rest list) depth))
    )

(defn n
  [list depth maxdepth]
    (cond 
        (= list nil) nil
        (= depth maxdepth) list
        (atom (first list)) (n (rest list) depth maxdepth)
        (= 0 (n (first list) (+ depth 1) maxdepth)) (n (last list) depth maxdepth)
        :default (n (first list) (+ depth 1) maxdepth))
    )

(defn myfind[mylist]
    (n mylist 0 (m mylist 0))
)
```

What I basically want is the output of the most nested list, as in:

```
(myfind '(1 2 3 (4 5) 6 ((7 8) 9)))
=> (7 8)
```

The goal is to use recursion and minimize the usage of builtin functions to achieve that.

What is wrong in this case?

Comment: `clojure.core/atom
([x] [x & options])
  Creates and returns an Atom with an initial value of x and zero or
  more options`...

Comment: I have removed atom and I still get the Stack overflow, the output is: 
StackOverflowError 
 ppj.core/m (form-init7572722406191330769.clj:4)
 ppj.core/m (form-init7572722406191330769.clj:6)
...

All the ideas how to solve this are very welcome :)

Comment: Can you provide a reason why won't you use library functions for solving this?

Comment: It's the requirements I have to follow ...

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn- deepest-with-depth [depth s]
  (let [nested-colls (filter coll? s)]
    (if (seq nested-colls)
      (mapcat (partial deepest-with-depth (inc depth)) nested-colls)
      [[depth s]])))

(defn deepest [s]
  (->> (deepest-with-depth 0 s)
       (apply max-key first)
       second))

> (deepest '(1 2 3 (4 5) 6 ((7 8) 9)))
(7 8)
```

Feel free to subsitute some function calls (e.g. `max-key`, `partial`) with their implementations, if they conflict with your requirements.

Comment: Thanks OlegTheCat, this is it!

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn- max-depth-entry [a-list]
  (let [sub-lists (filter coll? a-list)
        [depth list] (if (empty? sub-lists)
                           [0 a-list]
                           (apply max-key first (map max-depth-entry sub-lists)))]
    [(inc depth) list]))

(max-depth-entry '(1 2 3 (4 5) 6 ((7 8) 9)))
;[3 (7 8)]
```

Then

```
(def max-depth-sublist (comp second max-depth-entry))

(max-depth-sublist '(1 2 3 (4 5) 6 ((7 8) 9)))
;(7 8)
```

---

I owe the idea of using `max-key` to [OlegTheCat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38814305/1562315). I originally knitted my own, using `reduce`:

```
(defn- max-depth-entry [a-list]
  (let [sub-lists (filter coll? a-list)
        [a-list a-depth] (reduce
                          (fn ([] [a-list 0])
                            ([[as an :as asn] [s n :as sn]] (if (> n an) sn asn)))
                          (map max-depth-entry sub-lists))]
    [a-list (inc a-depth)]))
```

Then

```
(def max-depth-sublist (comp first max-depth-entry))
```

---

Now I'm ready to return to [Sequs Horribilis on 4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/112), which has stymied me until now.

Answer (score 0):

here is one more variant, with just classic old school solution, and no clojure specific sequence functions at all:

```
(defn deepest [items depth]
  (if (sequential? items)
    (let [[it1 d1 :as res1] (deepest (first items) (inc depth))
          [it2 d2 :as res2] (deepest (next items) depth)]
      (cond (>= depth (max d1 d2)) [items depth]
            (>= d1 d2) res1
            :else res2))
    [items -1]))
```

it is also notable by it's classic approach to the nested lists recursion: first you recur on `car`, then on `cdr`, and then combine these results.

```
user> (deepest '(1 2 3 (4 5) 6 ((7 8) 9)) 0)
[(7 8) 2]

user> (deepest '(1 2 3 (4 5) 6) 0)
[(4 5) 1]

user> (deepest '(1 2 3 (x ((y (z)))) (4 5) 6) 0)
[(z) 4]

user> (deepest '(1 2 3 (x ((y (z)))) (4 5 ((((((:xxx)))))))) 0)
[(:xxx) 7]

user> (deepest '(1 2 3 ((((((((nil)))))))) (x ((y (z)))) (4 5) 6) 0)
[(nil) 8]

user> (deepest '(1 2 3) 0)
[(1 2 3) 0]
```